# Internet Explorer 11 - Cookies not saving passed session

Tags: python, internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11

I'm having an issue with Internet Explorer 11, the issue we have is that our cookies dosen't save passed session, so as soon as a customer kills the browser and then starts it up again the cookies are gone in the wind.

info:

1. Website is a Python based website.
2. Cookies get set using Simple Cookie from python.
3. Cookies have an expire reaching for 1 year.
4. Cookies have the correct path.(Path is set to '/')
5. Cookies have the correct domain.
6. We are able to extract data from the cookie during session.

What i've checked/done:

1. Checked Safety Mode to make sure it's not on and not preventing the
   cookies to be set.
2. Double checked the cookies to make sure they are actually getting
   set and they are, they are there.
3. Made sure the cookies get set correctly and are readable by internet
   explorer.
4. Checked other browsers(Chrome, Firefox) They work perfectly fine
   there, the  issue seams limited to IE11.
5. Googled for answers

Code where cookies are saved looks like this(Python):
**self.cookie is Simple Cookie.
**data is a string

```
expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600*24*365)
self.cookie[self.prepend + key] = data
self.cookie[self.prepend + key]['expires'] = expiration.strftime('%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S PST')
self.cookie[self.prepend + key]['domain'] = self.domain
self.cookie[self.prepend + key]['path'] = '/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the IE browser setting, whether you checked the option "Delete browsing history when exit". Make sure it is unchecked.

[image]

Besides, you could refer to [this link and the demo](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), try to test it on your machine (it works well on my side). if still not working, perhaps the issue is related to your IE browser setting, try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings). If it works well, perhaps the issue is related your code, please recheck it.

Comment: Thanks, however i have checked that settings, more then once, also tried on other computers. Tried resetting the browser settings to :/ Works in any other browser except IE11.. but i make sure to double check it anyways, thanks

Comment: Whether the [JavaScript Cookies sample](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) works well in IE browser?  Please try to create a new page to test it. If still not working, perhaps there is some error with your IE browser, try to [repair it or re-install it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows). Besides, you could also try to use the [HTML Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store the data.